# postgresql GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS can not use array type?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

When I implement the following code in PL/pgSQL, some error occurs.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 10: GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_val[1] = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
```

Or anywhere I'm incorrect?
Any reply will be appreciated.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION merge_db5(key INT, data TEXT) RETURNS text AS
$$
    declare 
    text_val text[];
    text_result text;
    -- Declare an array to store the result.
BEGIN
    text_result := '';
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db(a,b) VALUES (key, data);
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN  
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_val[1] = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
    text_val[2] = COLUMN_NAME,
    text_val[3] = CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    text_val[4] = PG_DATATYPE_NAME,
    text_val[5] = MESSAGE_TEXT,
    text_val[6] = TABLE_NAME,
    text_val[7] = SCHEMA_NAME,
    text_val[8] = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
    text_val[9] = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT,
    text_val[10] = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    text_result = array_to_string(text_val,',','*');
    /*
    To save all the error messages to this array.
    */
  END;
    return text_result;
 END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Sorry to first use of this platform. I give my confusion again as follows.  When I implement the above code on pgsql, some error occurs.
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
    LINE 10: GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_val[1] = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
    Or anywhere I'm incorrect?
    Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use an array element there. The docs just say "variable". Does it work with a simple text variable as the target for your RETURNED_SQLSTATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not your bug. Target variable should be scalar. Arrays are not supported there.

A reason for this limit is very simple design of plpgsql parser and executor. Similar behave has a FOR IN LOOP statement. On second hand, this limit has practical sense (although it was not designed) - array update is not fast - arrays are immutable structures, so any update is emulated via creating modified copy - and less array updates usually means faster execution.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION merge_db5(key INT, data TEXT)
RETURNS text AS $$
  DECLARE 
     f1 text; f2 text; f3 text; f4 text; f5 text;
     f6 text; f7 text; f8 text; f9 text; f10 text;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db(a,b) VALUES (key, data);
    RETURN '';
  EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN  
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS f1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
                            f2 = COLUMN_NAME, f3 = CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                            f4 = PG_DATATYPE_NAME, f5 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                            f6 = TABLE_NAME, f7 = SCHEMA_NAME,
                            f8 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL, f9 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT,
                            f10 = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    RETURN array_to_string(ARRAY[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10], '*');
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```